# How to get condition with last day in Oracle SQL query

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to write the follwoing query but getting an error. Would apprecite if someone help me.
select Ldate from Dates
where Ldate >=LAST_DAY(SYSDATE)-1
The database date format is in string

`select Ldate from Dates  where Ldate >=LAST_DAY(SYSDATE)-1`

Comment: Don't store dates as strings. There are specific data types you should be using. Fix that, and things will work, and be reliable.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Don't store dates as string; use a `DATE` then your query would work.

If you do store it as a string (please don't) then convert it to a date in the query:

```sql
select Ldate
from   Dates
where  TO_DATE(Ldate, 'YYYY-MM-DD') >= LAST_DAY(TRUNC(SYSDATE))
```

*Note: update the `'YYYY-MM-DD'` format model to match your date format.*

Comment: The provided query does not work it says 'Invalid number format model". The second thing I want to mention is that we are storing "LDate" as a number, not as strings. Thanks

Comment: @user13058283 I'd mistyped, it should be `TO_DATE`.

Comment: Thanks again for the reply. With To_date, I got an error"  input value not long enough for date format"<select Ldate
from   DATES
where  TO_date(Ldate, 'YYYY-MM-DD') >= LAST_DAY(TRUNC(SYSDATE))

Comment: @user13058283 See the note on the answer. If your date format does not match `YYYY-MM-DD` then update it to a format that does.